# Multidimensional indexing of images

Tags: matlab, image, indexing, feature-extraction, cbir

I would like to know if there is a good way for indexing multidimensional objects (i.e. images). More precisely, I have a large collection of images on which I calculate n-dimensional feature vectors. There is a distance metric (i.e. L2-norm) defined over those feature vectors d(u,v). Given a key (an n-dimensional) `k`, the index should allow fast retrieval of feature vectors that are "close" to `k` (that is, their distance is small).

MATLAB code reference would be great...

Answer (score 2):

For distances [r-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtree)'s are often used. I think it can apply to n-dimensions, but I'm not sure if it will work with custom distance or dissimilarity functions. I think it's implemented in this [library](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20758-gml-lidark). It might help to convert your data to [n-dimensional coordinates](http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/stats/mdscaledemo.html#3).